# How to Navigate List of items on a page to a Different Page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I'm finding it difficult to push a '**submit'** button to a new page in Flutter. I tried to build a form to list items. On **submit**, the items show on the same page as the form. I don't like the idea.

The code below is the function for the purpose.

```
void _submitForm() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      final property = Property(
        name: _nameController.text,
        description: _descriptionController.text,
        pricePerMonth: double.parse(_priceController.text),
      );

      setState(() {
        _allProperties.add(property);
        _propertiesToShow = _getPropertiesToShow();
      });
      _resetForm();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
       const  SnackBar(
          content: Text('Property added successfully!'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        ),
      );
    }
```

This code returns the items to show on the same page.

**`setState(() {         _allProperties.add(property);         _propertiesToShow = _getPropertiesToShow();`**

I want it to navigate to a different page.

`ElevatedButton(`

`onPressed:` **`_submitForm`**`,`

`child: const Text('Submit'),`

`),`

When the **'submit'** button is pressed, I'd like to open a new page called '**AddedProperties()'**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using `_allProperties` in a `Listview.builder` on same page thats why you are getting new values on same page.
I suggest you to remove that `Listview.builder` from current page, create a new `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget` and put it there, e.g. AllProperites. Then on press of submit button you can simpli add your data into list and then navigate to AllProperites Screen.

just like this

```
void _submitForm() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      final property = Property(
        name: _nameController.text,
        description: _descriptionController.text,
        pricePerMonth: double.parse(_priceController.text),
      );
    }
    _allProperties.add(property);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllProperties()));
  }
```

Comment: okay. Thank you. Please should the **Void _submitForm()**  function be written in the AllProperties screen?

@Muzammil Hassan

Comment: no you have to right it on present screen, from where you want to navigate and can access it. or you can simply use any state management for better approach